# Most important attributes in matlab

Tags: matlab

so I have a dataset of 77 patients cancer patients and 12500+ attributes. I have applied Principal Component Analysis in order to filter the attributes to only retain the ones the explain the most variance.

My question is, are there techniques in Matlab, other than PCA, to identify the attributes with the most predictive power?

Comment: Just a little clarification: PCA will not "filter the attributes to only retain the ones that explain the most variance". PCA will generate a **new** set of attributes that are a linear combination of the original ones, with the first component being the one that has the largest variance. If you want to select the original attributes that best explain the dataset, PCA is not exactly what you are aiming for.

Comment: You can use "Fischer" vectors @S. Fischer XD

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to cleverly "reduce the dimensionality" of your dataset. One is **Feature Transformation** (that includes, for example, PCA), and the other one is **Feature Selection**.

It seems that you are looking for a Feature Selection algorithm, that would retain the most informative *original attributes*. On the contrary, a Feature Transformation algorithm will generate a *new* set of attributes!

As for your exact question, there are multiple choices you can make. Keep in mind that, naively, each Feature Selection algorithm will have to choose the best features according to "how well" those features alone can model the problem.

For a MATLAB built-in implementation, if you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox installed, you can use the "[Sequential feature selection](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/sequentialfs.html)" function `sequentialfs`.